# Assertion & documentation in a class for methods that are expected in derived classes

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.6, assertions, docstring

Say I make a class named Bird which I only want to be used as a parent class and derived classes are expected to have a method `flap_wings`:

```
class Bird:

    def fly(self):
        self.flap_wings()
```

An expected derived class might look like:

```
class Eagle(Bird):

    def flap_wings(self):
        print('flapping wings')
```

What is a nice, clear way for `Bird` to both assert that its derived classes have the method `flap_wings` as well as include documentation on what `flap_wings` is expected to do?

Right now, I'm using `__init_subclass__`:

```
class Bird:

    def fly(self):
        self.flap_wings()

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        assert hasattr(cls, 'flap_wings'), (
            "Derived classes have to have a flap_wings method which should "
            "print 'flapping wings'."
        )
```

But, the assert expression only shows up after you create a Bird class and is not a "real" docstring that can be accessed through `help`.

I know this is an open ended question but what are other better ways? It's not against the rules to define `flap_wings` within `Bird` first, maybe just with the body `pass` and a docstring. But I just couldn't find the "standard" ways to handle this situation. So I'm looking for any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the references to the previous questions. I was using `__init_subclass__` with the impression that it was a simpler way to do what metaclasses did here, but I guess `__init_subclass__` just doesn't offer enough to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `abc` library for abstract methods:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import six

class Bird(six.with_metaclass(ABCMeta)):
    def fly(self):
        """Take flight.

        Notes
        -----
        This depends on the abstract method `flap_wings`. If you've
        not implemented this at the subclass level, your subclass
        cannot be properly instantiated.
        """
        self.flap_wings()

    @abstractmethod
    def flap_wings(self):
        """Subclasses must implement this"""
```

This establishes a contract of sorts. Any subclass that does NOT implement the `flap_wings` method will raise an error on instantiation:

```
class Flamingo(Bird):
    pass

>>> Flamingo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Flamingo with abstract methods flap_wings
```

Whereas a sub-class that implements the abstract method will work fine:

```
class BlueJay(Bird):
    def flap_wings(self):
        print("Flappity flap")

>>> BlueJay().fly()
Flappity flap
```

As far as documenting the subclass, since all subclasses inherit the `fly` method, you could include in its docstring that it calls the `flap_wings` method and expects it to be present.

Comment: Thanks for this, especially showing the organization of the docstrings. And good choice of birds. I'll use metaclasses.